# How do I burn an ISO on a USB drive on Mac OS X?

Tags: mac, usb-flash-drive, iso-image, bootable-media

what's the best way to get an ISO "burned" to a USB stick on a Mac? Restoring using Disk Utility does not work.

The ISO is ubuntu mini.iso. It is the minimalist install ISO for installing ubuntu. It needs to be bootable on a PC. I am trying to install ubuntu on a PC that has no CD-ROM. The only other computer I have around is a macbook.

Comment: Can you please be a bit more descriptive in what you are trying to accomplish. I think I have an idea of what the problem is but your question is vague

Comment: I'm trying to "burn" a bootable ISO of the ubuntu mini.iso onto a USB stick for use on a PC. The PC in question does not have a CD-ROM. I don't have any other linux or win machines around.

Answer (score 126):

Directly from the [How to install Ubuntu on MacBook using USB Stick](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/How%20to%20install%20Ubuntu%20on%20MacBook%20using%20USB%20Stick) page
(my formatting):

1. Download the desired file
2. Open the Terminal (in /Applications/Utilities/ or query **Terminal** in Spotlight)
3. Convert the .iso file to .img using the convert option of hdiutil (e.g., `hdiutil convert -format UDRW -o ~/path/to/target.img ~/path/to/ubuntu.iso`)
4. Note: OS X tends to put the .dmg ending on the output file automatically.  Remove the .dmg extension as necessary, `mv ~/path/to/target.img{.dmg,}`
5. Run `diskutil list` to get the current list of devices
6. Insert your flash media
7. Run `diskutil list` again and determine the device node assigned to your flash media (e.g. `/dev/disk2`)
8. Run `diskutil unmountDisk /dev/diskN` (replace `N` with the disk number from the last command; in the previous example, `N` would be 2)
9. Execute `sudo dd if=/path/to/downloaded.img of=/dev/rdiskN bs=1m` (replace `/path/to/downloaded.img` with the path where the image file is located; for example, `./ubuntu.img` or `./ubuntu.dmg`).
10. Using `/dev/rdisk` instead of `/dev/disk` may be faster.

    - If you see the error `dd: Invalid number '1m'`, you are using GNU `dd`. Use the same command but replace `bs=1m` with `bs=1M`.
    - If you see the error `dd: /dev/diskN: Resource busy`, make sure the disk is not in use. Start **Disk Utility.app** and unmount (don't eject) the drive.
11. Run `diskutil eject /dev/diskN` and remove your flash media when the command completes
12. Restart your Mac and hold down <kbd>Alt</kbd> while the Mac is restarting to choose the USB stick

Note: On newer Macs you *might* have to install an [EFI boot manager](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) to boot from USB.

See also: [Download Ubuntu Desktop](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop).

Comment: Maybe people were not "blindly" up voting this. Maybe ... like me, they googled how to burn an ISO to a USB drive on MacOS, ya know THE TITLE OF THIS QUESTION ... found this ... and it worked. Geez. +1

Comment: I'm not sure what all the uproar is about.  The answer is 100% on topic, works perfectly, and the resulting drive isn't any more platform-specific than the ISO you burned to it.  I've used these instructions to burn OS installer ISO's (Ubuntu, WinXP, etc.) to a flash drive and the result worked perfectly on a PC.

Comment: Nope, I just failed to boot on a PC with the USB key created this method on my MacMini. The problem seems to be it lacks the ability to be booted on by the BIOS.

Comment: If you want to see progress, ensure you have `pv` installed, and run `pv /path/to/downloaded.img | sudo dd of=/dev/rdiskN bs=1m` instead of `sudo dd if=/path/to/downloaded.img of=/dev/rdiskN bs=1m`.

Comment: This failed for me as well, I needed to use @neesh answer to get the USB to be bootable on a PC. The conversion from iso to img must not preserve any boot support. Also wondering if simply skipping the conversion would work too--but as rab points out below, might not work with UEFI.

Comment: I skipped conversion, and installed successfully on a dell with uefi turned off.

Comment: I found that using Disk Utility to identify the flash drive is way easier than trying to find it in diskutil. You can unmount it from there too.

Answer (score 18):

I had a very similar problem that none of these answered.

It's worth checking out [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/). It will create a bootable USB disk on a Mac for a PC.

Comment: Once done, unetbootin said that I had to boot it on a PC and that it won't boot on a Mac. Trying the command line suggestion now.

Comment: For a Chrome Pixel, the UNetbootin method worked, command line didn't.

Comment: It is to my understanding that UNetbootin doesn't work on Mountain Lion.

Answer (score 14):

There is no need to convert the ISO to an IMG. I wasn't willing to convert an image first. [This](http://www.techusers.net/6/how-create-linux-bootable-usb-drive-mac-osx-using-dd-command) has easier steps, outlined below.

Start by listing the current disks and volumes:

```
diskutil list
```

Now unmount the current volume for the disk you are about to overwrite. (X = Drive number, in my case was 1):

```
diskutil unmountDisk /dev/diskX
```

Now dd the iso directly to the usb (again replace X with drive number of your USB drive):

```
sudo dd if=/pathto/mini.iso of=/dev/diskX bs=1m
```

Done!

Comment: This used to work, but I think the newer UEFI boot software doesn't understand the resulting file (2017). BIOS systems will work though. A way that works and is still easy is to use OS X's Boot Camp Assistant. Point it to an ISO and USB key, and it creates a UEFI bootable stick.

Answer (score 7):

This is a very old question but still benefits from updated answers.

[Etcher](http://etcher.io) is now the solution recommended by [Ubuntu](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-macos#0) to burn iso images to a USB drive.

Etcher makes the process almost painless if you are not comfortable with the command line. It's only 3 steps and worked on the first try for me.

Comment: Where does Ubuntu recommend this?

Comment: [Create a bootable USB stick on macOS](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-macos#0)

Comment: Etcher worked really well, thx

Answer (score 4):

The way to do this using DiskUtility is to first format the drive using Diskutility and then copy over the files from the mounted iso to the newly formated drive using cp -R. Ex: cp -R /Volumes/mounted_iso/* /Volumes/formated_drive/

When formatting be sure to pick the ntfs file system and make the disk bootable by picking the correct option from the Options menu in the erase tab.

Comment: This was what worked for me to burn a Win10 bootable USB from macOS Sierra. The conversion from iso to img must strip out the master boot record on the disk. By reformatting with MBR and copying files, worked great.

Answer (score 2):

1. Ensure the USB Key is properly formatted (Master Boot Record, FAT32 - if necessary NTFS using [NTFS-3G](http://www.ntfs-3g.org/))
2. You can try using the Restore feature in Disk Utility by clicking on the USB key's volume, then clicking on the Restore tab and choosing the ISO to restore onto it.
3. If step 2 fails, you can do this manually by running `ditto` or `cp -r`; eg. `ditto /Volumes/NAME_OF_MOUNTED_ISO /Volumes/NAME_OF_USB_KEY` or `cp -r /Volumes/NAME_OF_MOUNTED_ISO /Volumes/NAME_OF_USB_KEY` to manually copy all the files (including hidden ones)

Comment: @Chealion thanks for your response. I was actually trying to get an Ubuntu ISO onto my USB, so I eventually just used the Ubuntu install disc to run it in Live Mode on my Macbook. From there I had access to the USB-Creator utility.

Comment: Also @Chealion I won't have time to verify your answer as correct anytime soon as I won't be near my Mac for a while (but I do know that Disk Utility was not working for me) If someone else verify's and upvotes, I'll mark as correct.

Answer (score 2):

[Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.github.io/) is a tool that installs ISOs on USB keys, or you can use dropdown menus to select distributions right there in the tool.

Slightly easier than doing `dd` on the command line yourself.

Comment: Unetbootin dates back to 2008 at least. Another answer here already covered this option

Answer (score 1):

I have done this frequently on my MacBook Pro for installing OS on new laptops. From my own experience, there is not a single tool that can create bootable USB from all ISO images. You should pick up the right tool for specific ISO file.

Mostly, you should format USB drive to FAT32 first as NTFS is not supported by Mac.

For burning Linux ISO on Mac, [**UNetbootin**](https://unetbootin.github.io/) is superior than other tools like Etcher. And it consumes less computing resource.

For burning Windows ISO on Mac, **UUByte ISO Editor** is more efficient and user friendly. In addition, it works seamlessly on latest macOS Big Sur. You can check the tutorial for burning ISO to USB on Mac from [here](https://www.uubyte.com/burn-iso-to-usb-on-mac.html).

For Raspbian PI based ISO for embedded development, [**balenaEtcher**](https://www.balena.io/etcher/) is more recommended.

Comment: you should specify that UUByte ISO Editor is a paid app

Answer (score 0):

I've user [SuperDuper](http://www.shirt-pocket.com/SuperDuper/SuperDuperDescription.html) for this task before. It does the job and not much else. Like a good program should :-) The full version is not free ($30) but you get what you need for free:

> You can download SuperDuper! v2.6.2
>   right now and back up and clone your
>   drives for free— forever!

Comment: Super Duper! doesn't support partitions that aren't formatted as HFS, so it's useless here.