# How to burn iso image with Windows 8 Consumer Preview to USB memory stick on Mac OS X

Tags: windows, mac, iso-image

I want to install the Windows 8 Consumer Preview on my netbook Samsung NB30. The netbook doesn't have a CD or DVD drive, so I want to burn the image to a USB memory stick. I only have Mac OS X machines at home currently, so I've tried to use the Disk Utility and the restore function, but it fails with a 'cannot validate source' error message.

Any idea how to put the ISO on USB stick using Mac?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I burn an ISO on a USB drive on Mac OS X?](http://superuser.com/questions/63654/how-do-i-burn-an-iso-on-a-usb-drive-on-mac-os-x)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This windows tool should get the job done.](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msstore/html/pbPage.Help_Win7_usbdvd_dwnTool)

.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to run the tool in Windows 7 virtual machine and it did the job for me.

Comment: This method is recommended by the Windows 8 download page. http://windows.microsoft.com/en-AU/windows-8/iso

Comment: @Daniel your link refers to the same tool I linked to.

Comment: The point was Microsoft recommends this method.

Comment: Tool is hosted at the Microsoft store with instructions from Microsoft, what more of a recommendation does one need.