# How do I burn the Win8 Consumer Preview ISO to a USB on a Mac?

Tags: macos, usb, boot, windows-8-preview

So someone already asked this question ([How to burn iso image with Windows 8 Consumer Preview to USB memory stick on Mac OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/396512/)) but was happy with a non-answer. They asked how to install from Mac, someone suggested a Windows app, and they were happy with that. I cannot run a Windows app from my Mac so I would like an actual answer. Since I cannot comment on that answer, I thought I would make my own question.

If you have the ISO for the Windows 8 Consumer Preview, and you use the disk utility to create a USB from the ISO, the USB will not be bootable (for some reason). I have tried a few other utilities and none seem to work. Everyone is suggesting to do this on Windows, I do not have Windows. There must be a way to do this from a Mac.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to burn iso image with Windows 8 Consumer Preview to USB memory stick on Mac OS X](http://superuser.com/questions/396512/how-to-burn-iso-image-with-windows-8-consumer-preview-to-usb-memory-stick-on-mac) also see [How do I burn an ISO on a USB drive on Mac OS X?](http://superuser.com/questions/63654/how-do-i-burn-an-iso-on-a-usb-drive-on-mac-os-x)

Comment: Welcome to SU -- To get different/better answers to an existing question please [set a bounty](http://superuser.com/privileges/set-bounties) instead of duplicating the question.

Answer (score 2):

Just follow these steps:  [How to Make a Bootable USB on a Mac](http://www.ehow.com/how_5142897_make-bootable-usb-mac.html#page=0)

And when you are done with the bootable flash, just extract all the content of the WIN8 iso to your bootable flash drive. It will make you have a bootable flash drive with Windows 8 installeable from it. Boot your machine with this pen drive and install Windows 8.

Answer (score 0):

I have a San Disk Cruzer Blade 16 GB pendrive. If you format the pendrive with fat 32 filesystem you only have to copy and paste the contet of the ISO file. When you restart your mac hold down alt (option) key and now you can boot up from your pendrive.