# Burn Windows 10 ISO to DVD on Mojave

Tags: iso-image, macos-mojave

I have a portable DVD burner and trying to make a bootable Windows 10 installer. How can I do this on Mojave?

It is for DVD not USB

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/63654/how-do-i-burn-an-iso-on-a-usb-drive-on-mac-os-x and https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/103874/creating-a-bootable-usb-of-windows-8-1-on-os-x though, tbh, it's ***so*** much easier to do it on Windows with the Media Creation Tool that that would be my first recommendation - find a Win machine & do it there; or Parallels/VMWare, or Boot Camp etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I burn an ISO on a USB drive on Mac OS X?](https://superuser.com/questions/63654/how-do-i-burn-an-iso-on-a-usb-drive-on-mac-os-x)

Comment: If you want to write it to a DVD (not a USB stick) then you should be able to do it from direct from finder.  Do you have the *"Burn Disk Image"* option as shown in the pictures [here](http://osxdaily.com/2015/11/22/burn-disc-images-os-x-finder/)?

Comment: @lx07 - I was wondering whether that still existed if you have a blank disk in the drive. Couldn't find anything to test it with.

Comment: No Burn option on Mojave. The duplicate post is for USB not DVD, which is much different.

Comment: @alvisryan If so find and install any third-party CD/DVD burning software. Any software you'll find has that option. But really you shouldn't be using optical media for Windows. Any USB stick is much faster and reusable and I'm not sure that a DVD can be used for UEFI installations (Windows 7 actually requires USB for UEFI).